# Angular 7 NGB accordion Menu not rendering

Tags: angular, accordion, ng-bootstrap

I am trying to render just the following accordion menu straight from the ng bootstrap site:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <h1 class="text-center">
      Discounts
    </h1>
    <div class="row">
      <ngb-accordion #acc="ngbAccordion">
        <ngb-panel id="toggle-1" title="First panel">
          <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia
            aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor,
            sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica,
            craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings
            occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus
            labore sustainable VHS.
          </ng-template>
        </ngb-panel>
        <ngb-panel id="toggle-2" title="Second">
          <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia
            aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor,
            sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica,
            craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings
            occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus
            labore sustainable VHS.
          </ng-template>
        </ngb-panel>
      </ngb-accordion>
    </div>
      .
      .
      .
```

We have angular 7, ng-bootstrap 4+ and from what I can tell everything should work. We are at a loss right now. Here is my App Module:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavMenuTopComponent } from './views/common/nav-menu-top/nav-menu-top.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './views/common/login.component';
import { Ng2SmartTableModule } from 'ng2-smart-table';
import { AdministrationAnnouncementsComponent } from './views/administration/announcements/administrationAnnouncements.component';
import { AdministrationAppointmentsComponent } from './views/administration/appointments/administrationAppointments.component';
//import { AdministrationAppointmentsComponent } from './views/administration/appointments/administrationAppointments_2.component';
import { AdministrationArchivesComponent } from './views/administration/archives/administrationArchives.component';
import { AdministrationCallsComponent } from './views/administration/calls/administrationCalls.component';
import { AdministrationCompaniesComponent } from './views/administration/companies/administrationCompanies.component';
import { AdministrationCustomersComponent } from './views/administration/customers/administrationCustomers.component';
import { AdministrationEmployeesComponent } from './views/administration/employees/administrationEmployees.component';
import { AdministrationInvoicesComponent } from './views/administration/invoices/administrationInvoices.component';
import { AdministrationObservationsComponent } from './views/administration/observations/administrationObservations.component';
import { AdministrationProblemsComponent } from './views/administration/problems/administrationProblems.component';
import { AdministrationQuickInvoicesComponent } from './views/administration/quickInvoices/administrationQuickInvoices.component';
//import { TechnicianAppointmentsComponent } from './views/technician/appointments/technicianAppointments.component';
//import { TechnicianDiscountsComponent } from './views/technician/discounts/technicianDiscounts.component';
//import { TechnicianHomeComponent } from './views/technician/home/technicianHome.component';
//import { TechnicianInvoicesComponent } from './views/technician/invoices/technicianInvoices.component';
//import { TechnicianOptionsComponent } from './views/technician/options/technicianOptions.component';
//import { TechnicianProblemsComponent } from './views/technician/problems/technicianProblems.component';
//import { TechnicianReviewsComponent } from './views/technician/reviews/technicianReviews.component';
//import { TechnicianSolutionsComponent } from './views/technician/solutions/technicianSolutions.component';
import { jqxGridComponent } from 'jqwidgets-scripts/jqwidgets-ts/angular_jqxgrid';
import { JwtModule } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
import { AdminAuthGuard } from './guards/admin-auth-guard.service';
import { TechAuthGuard } from './guards/tech-auth-guard.service';
import { companyList } from './views/administration/partials/companyList/companyList.component';
import { employeeForm } from './views/administration/partials/employeeForm/employeeForm.component';
import { ButtonRenderComponent } from './views/administration/partials/button-render/button.render.component';
import { employeeSelectForm } from './views/administration/partials/employeeSelectForm/employeeSelectForm.component';
import { customerForm } from './views/administration/partials/customerForm/customerForm.component';
import { cityStateZipSelector } from './views/administration/partials/cityStateZipSelector/cityStateZip.component';
import { customerCreateModal } from './views/administration/partials/customerCreationModal/customerCreationModal.component';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { createCustomerForm } from './views/administration/partials/createCustomerForm/createCustomerForm.component';
import { customerUpdateForm } from './views/administration/partials/customerUpdateForm/customerUpdateForm.component';
import { employeeCreateForm } from './views/administration/partials/employeeCreateForm/employeeCreateForm.component';
import { CounterComponent } from './views/common/counter/counter.component';
import { jqxSchedulerComponent } from 'jqwidgets-scripts/jqwidgets-ts/angular_jqxscheduler';
import { TaskManagementComponent } from './views/administration/taskManagement/taskManagement.component';
import { TaskManagementHomeComponent } from './views/administration/taskManagement/taskManagementHome/taskManagementHome.component';
import { ToastrModule } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { TaskManagementCategoriesComponent } from './views/administration/taskManagement/taskManagementCategories/taskManagementCategories.component';
import { DemoTechComponent } from './views/technician/demoHome/demoHome.component';
import { AppointmentMaintenance } from './views/technician/appointmentMaintenance/appointmentMaintenance.component';
import { getCompanySalesTax } from './views/administration/partials/getCompanySalesTax/getCompanySalesTax.component';
import { getEmployeeList } from './views/administration/partials/employeeList/employeeList.component';
import { getObservationsList } from './views/administration/partials/ObservationsList/observationsList.component';
import { getCategorySubcategoryList } from './views/administration/partials/CategorySubcategoryList/categorySubcategory.component';
import { ObservationsComponent } from './views/technician/observations/observations.component';
import { FindingsComponent } from './views/technician/findings/findings.component';
import { TechOptionsComponent } from './views/technician/tech-options/tech-options.component';
import { CustomerReviewComponent } from './views/technician/customer-review/customer-review.component';
import { DiscountsComponent } from './views/technician/discounts/discounts.component';
import { MaterialNotesComponent } from './views/technician/material-notes/material-notes.component';
import { TechHomeComponent } from './views/technician/techHome/techHome.component';
import { SalesTaxFormComponent } from './views/administration/partials/salesTaxForm/salesTaxForm.component';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { AnnouncementsDisplayComponent } from './views/technician/partials/announcements/announcements.component';
import { optionCopyMenuComponent } from './views/technician/partials/optionCopy/optionCopyMenu.component';
import { TechLayoutComponent } from './views/common/techLayout/techLayout.component';
import { AdminLayoutComponent } from './views/common/adminLayout/adminLayout.component';
import { AppointmentDetails } from './views/technician/appointmentDetails/appointmentDetails.component';
import { techHeaderComponent } from './views/technician/partials/techHeader/techHeader.component';
import { DiscountFormComponent } from './views/administration/partials/companyDiscountsForm/discountsForm.component';
import { ServiceChargeFormComponent } from './views/administration/partials/companyServiceChargeForm/serviceChargeForm.component';
import { ObservationListComponent } from './views/technician/partials/observationList/observationList.component';
import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';

export function jwtTokenGetter() {
  return sessionStorage.getItem("fleetbooks_JWT");
};

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavMenuTopComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    AdministrationAnnouncementsComponent,
    AppointmentDetails,
    AdministrationAppointmentsComponent,
    AdministrationArchivesComponent,
    AdministrationCallsComponent,
    AdministrationCompaniesComponent,
    AdministrationCustomersComponent,
    AdministrationEmployeesComponent,
    AdministrationInvoicesComponent,
    AdministrationObservationsComponent,
    AdministrationProblemsComponent,
    AdministrationQuickInvoicesComponent,
    //TechnicianAppointmentsComponent,
    //TechnicianDiscountsComponent,
    //TechnicianHomeComponent,
    //TechnicianInvoicesComponent,
    //TechnicianOptionsComponent,
    //TechnicianProblemsComponent,
    //TechnicianReviewsComponent,
    //TechnicianSolutionsComponent,
    jqxGridComponent,
    jqxSchedulerComponent,
    companyList,
    employeeForm,
    employeeSelectForm,
    employeeCreateForm,
    customerForm,
    cityStateZipSelector,
    createCustomerForm,
    customerUpdateForm,
    customerCreateModal,
    CounterComponent,
    TaskManagementComponent,
    TaskManagementHomeComponent,
    TaskManagementCategoriesComponent,
    DemoTechComponent,
    AppointmentMaintenance,
    getEmployeeList,
    getCompanySalesTax,
    getObservationsList,
    getCategorySubcategoryList,
    ButtonRenderComponent,
    ObservationsComponent,
    FindingsComponent,
    TechOptionsComponent,
    CustomerReviewComponent,
    DiscountsComponent,
    MaterialNotesComponent,
    TechHomeComponent,
    SalesTaxFormComponent,
    AnnouncementsDisplayComponent,
    TechLayoutComponent,
    AdminLayoutComponent,
    optionCopyMenuComponent,
    techHeaderComponent,
    DiscountFormComponent,
    ServiceChargeFormComponent,
    ObservationListComponent,
  ],
  entryComponents: [ButtonRenderComponent],
  imports: [
    Ng2SmartTableModule,
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    JwtModule.forRoot({
      config: {
        tokenGetter: jwtTokenGetter,
        whitelistedDomains: [environment.baseUrl],
        blacklistedRoutes: [],
      }
    }),
    NgbModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ToastrModule.forRoot({
      timeOut: 3000,
      positionClass: 'toast-top-right',
    }),
    FontAwesomeModule
  ],
  providers: [AdminAuthGuard, TechAuthGuard],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I know it is long, I can take out all the useless stuff if needed. I can also post my package.json if needed. The code that I linked above renders as the following if I inspect element:

`<ngb-accordion activeids="ngb-panel-0" class="accordion" role="tablist" ng-reflect-active-ids="ngb-panel-0"><!----></ngb-accordion>`

There is no console error, no compile error, nothing. It just doesn't appear on the page and when I go to look in inspect element that is all I see.

This is the tutorial I was looking at for reference: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/accordion/api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double-check your console for errors that may be causing it to not render.